# Partitons in Linux

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have switched to Ubuntu for about a year. when i used windows,... i didn't use to have different partition for movies/photos and i used to library folders in C:\ and so it was fine for me when i only created /home partition while installing Ubuntu and when its down, i just moved my movies to /home/user/Videos and photos and documents to /home/user/Pictures .../Documents and ... . but in this past year who ever i invited to Ubuntu said that they are using different partitions for movies/pictures/documents/music and they don't want to use directories for that. so my question is can we create something like /home but only for movies, i mean only a different and empty partition that mounts like a Usb or hard? please help me with that so i can increase Gnu/Linux users in my family :)

Comment: You can mount a partition to a subdirectory of `/media`. it will be shown like a "disk". But it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Yeah I don't understand this kind of sorting medias and data but its very common between people in my country (IRAN). so would you please explain a little bit more about this /media thing...?

Comment: of course you can create & mount as many partitions as you need  each on /media/photos / media/vidéos & so on   and if you want them accessible from /home/photos  create a symbolic link to the partition you want. example : `sudo mkdir /media/photos && mount /dev/sdd1 /media/photos && ln -s /media/photos /home/photos`

Comment: @francoisP I make a directory in `/media/videos` but when i mount it it give me error: cant find it in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: command is `mount mediapath directorypath` you cannot call just `mount directorypath` but in cas you added it in /etc/fstab manually once

Comment: Data partition(s) can be on same drive or another drive. You have to create mount point, mount partition, and give yourself ownership & permissions. If internal drive permanently mount using fstab. Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: @francoisP ok but how can i understand Mediapath for directory i make in `/medie`?

Comment: mediapath is hardware path  /dev/somethink this only you can know YOUR machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create partition using **gparted**.

Install it from terminal:

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

and then you can move free space from your disk creating new partitions each one dedicated for videos, photos, documents or whatever you want.

Then you can mount  partitions as a subdirectories of /media directly using a file manager.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: I'm happy that my suggestion was useful for you